# Efficient parallelization of operations on two dimensional array operations in python

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, joblib, parallel.for

I'm trying to parallelize operations on two dimensional array using `joblib` library in python. Here is the code I have

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

# The code below just aggregates the base_array to form a new two dimensional array
base_array = np.ones((2**12, 2**12), dtype=np.uint8)
def compute_average(i, j):
    return np.uint8(np.mean(base_array[i*4: (i+1)*4, j*4: (j+1)*4]))

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
new_array = np.array(Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(compute_average)(i, j) 
                                        for i in xrange(0,1024) for j in xrange(0,1024)), dtype=np.uint8)
```

The above code takes more time than the basic nested for loop below.

```
new_array_nested = np.ones((2**10, 2**10), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in xrange(0,1024):
    for j in xrange(0,1024):
         new_array_nested[i,j] = compute_average(i,j)
```

Why are parallel operations taking more time? How can the efficiency of the above code be improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sup>*Wow! Absolutely loved your code. It worked like a charm **improving the total efficiency by 400x.** I'll try to read more about numba and jit compilers, but can you write briefly of why it is so efficient. Thanks once again for all the help! – [Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4522548/ram) Jan 3 '18 at 20:30*</sup>

<sup>We can quite easily get somewhere **under `77 [ms]`**, but it takes mastering a few steps to get there, so let's start:</sup>

---

### Q: why parallel operations are taking more time?

Because the proposed step with **`joblib`** creates that many full-scale process copies - so as to escape from the GIL-stepped [pure-**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) dancing ( one-after-another ) but (!) this includes add-on costs of all the memory transfers ( very expensive / sensitive for indeed large **`numpy`** arrays ) of all variables and the whole python interpreter and its internal state, before it gets to start doing a first step on the "usefull" work on your "payload"-calculation strategy,
so
**the sum of all these instantiation overheads can easily become larger, than an overhead-agnostic expectation of an inversely proportional `1 / N` factor**,
where you set the `N ~ num_cores`.

[For **details,** read the mathematical formulation in the tail part of Amdahl's Law re-formulation **here**.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

---

### Q:can help improve the efficiency of the above code?

**Save as much as possible** on all overhead costs:
- where possible:
 - **on process spawn-side**, try to use **`n_jobs = ( num_cores - 1 )`** to let more space for the "main" process going forward and benchmark if performance goes up
- **on process termination-side**, avoiding to collect-and-construct a new ( possibly great in size ) object from returning values, but rather pre-allocate a just-enough large process-local data structures and return some efficient, serialised for easy and non-blocking coalescing of the per-partes returned results' alignments.

Both of these "hidden" costs are your main design enemies, as they get linearly added to the pure-**`[SERIAL]`** part of the computing-path of the whole problem solution ( [**ref.:** the effects of both of these in the **overhead-strict** Amdahl's Law formula](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) )

---

### Experiments & Results:

```
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()
>>> base_array = np.ones( (2**12, 2**12), dtype = np.uint8 )
>>> base_array.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA      : True
  WRITEABLE    : True
  ALIGNED      : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> def compute_average_per_TILE(               TILE_i,   TILE_j ): // NAIVE MODE
...     return np.uint8( np.mean( base_array[ 4*TILE_i:4*(TILE_i+1),
...                                           4*TILE_j:4*(TILE_j+1)
...                                           ]
...                               )
...                      )
... 
>>> aClk.start(); _ = compute_average_per_TILE( 12,13 ); aClk.stop()
25110
  102
  109
   93
```

This takes about **`93 [us]`** per one shot. Having expectation of about  `1024*1024*93 ~ 97,517,568 [us]` to cover the mean-processing over the whole `base_array`.

Experimentally, here one nicely can see the impact of not very well handled overheads, the naive-nested experiment took:

```
>>> aClk.start(); _ = [ compute_average_per_TILE( i, j )
                                              for i    in xrange(1024)
                                              for    j in xrange(1024)
                        ]; aClk.stop()
26310594
^^...... 
26310594 / 1024. / 1024. == 25.09 [us/cell]
```

**which is about 3.7x less** ( due to not incurred "tail"-part ( assignment of individual returned values ) overheads 2**20 times, but just once, at the terminal assignment.

Yet, more surprises to come.

---

### What is a proper tool here?

There is never a universal rule, no one-size-fits-all.

**Given**
not more than just a 4x4 matrix tile is going to be processes per call ( taking actually **less than `25 [us]`** per a proposed **`joblib`**-orchestrated spawn of `2**20` calls, distributed over ~ **`.cpu_count()`** fully instantiated processes by the original proposal

```
...( joblib.Parallel( n_jobs = num_cores )( 
     joblib.delayed( compute_average )( i, j ) 
                                    for i    in xrange( 1024 )
                                    for    j in xrange( 1024 )
     )
```

there is indeed a space to improve the performance.

For these small-scale matrices ( not all problems are so happy in this sense ), one can expect best results from smarter-memory access patterns and from reducing python GIL-originated weaknesses.

As the per-call span is just a 4x4 micro sized computation, a way better will be to harness smart vectorisation ( all data fit in cache, so in-cache computing is a holiday journey for hunting an utmost performance )

The best ( still very naively vectorised code )
was able to get from `~ 25 [us/cell]` to **less than `~ 74 [ns/cell]`** ( having there still a space for better aligned processing, as it took **`~ 4.6 [ns]` / a `base_array` cell processing** ), so expect yet another level of speedups, if in-cache optimised vectorised code will get crafted properly.

### In `77 [ms]` ?! Worth doing that right, isn't it?

Not 97 seconds,
not 25 seconds,
**but less than `77 [ms]`** in just a few strokes of keyboard, and more could have got squeezed off, if better optimising a call-signature:

```
>>> import numba
>>> @numba.jit( nogil = True, nopython = True )
... def jit_avg2( base_IN, ret_OUT ):  // all pre-allocated memory for these data-structures
...     for i in np.arange( 1024 ):    // vectorised-code ready numpy iterator
...         for j in np.arange( 1024 ):// vectorised-code ready numpy iterator 
...             ret_OUT[i,j] = np.uint8( np.mean( base_IN[4*i:4*(i+1),
...                                                       4*j:4*(j+1)
...                                                       ]
...                                               )
...                                      )
...     return                         // avoid terminal assignment costs
... 

>>> aClk.start(); _ = jit_avg2( base_array, mean_array ); aClk.stop()
1586182 (even with all the jit-compilation circus, it was FASTER than GIL-stepped nested fors ...)
  76935
  77337
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the intricacies and the Amdahl's Law. The first part of the response of why it is taking more time was clearly understood. However, it is still not clear how to improve the efficiency. I have played with various values for n_jobs (from 5 to 23 on a 24 core machine) and the efficiency is still not improved (the time it took was pretty much remained the same). Can you please elaborate on the third point in pre-allocating and serializing the return values? In general, how to compute these aggregations efficiently.

Comment: Glad the view has helped you in further C/S investigations. Process instantiations are expensive, their "optimum" count is a sort of final touch, not the step #1 in the search. This was the reason to mention a step to A/B-test with one-less processes being instantiated in the `n_jobs` class-attribute setting. The **main "duty"** is indeed in the **battle against the pure-`[SERIAL]`** sections of the problem computing-graph, as Gene AMDAHL has explained more than a half century ago already ( +having it also extended by **not forgetting** about all-"*newly*"-*added* - also serial - overheads )

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you point me in the direction on how to improve the pure-[SERIAL] part of the problem? It takes ~9s for nested loop and ~30s for parallelized code. I will run this code snippet multiple number of times and it'll be infeasible with these execution times. I can completely go away from this solution, if there is alternative efficient solution for compute this aggregation.

Comment: Ok, got hands dirty with you ... Doable in less than `77 [ms]` ?! Worth doing than right, isn't it? Hope you like it at least as I did.

Comment: Wow! Absolutely loved your code. It worked like a charm improving the total efficiency by 400x. I'll try to read more about numba and jit compilers, but can you write briefly of why it is so efficient.

Thanks once again for all the help!