# Poor scaling of multiprocessing Pool.map() on a list of large objects: How to achieve better parallel scaling in python?

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallelism-amdahl

Let us define :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
def func(x):
    for i in range(1000):
        i**2
    return 1
```

Notice that `func()` does something and it always returns a small number `1`.

Then, I compare an 8-core parallel `Pool.map()` v/s a serial, python built in, `map()`

```
n=10**3
a=np.random.random(n).tolist()

with Pool(8) as p:
    %timeit -r1 -n2  p.map(func,a)
%timeit -r1 -n2  list(map(func,a))
```

This gives :

```
38.4 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
200 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
```

which shows quite good parallel scaling. Because I use 8 cores, and `38.3 [ms]` is roughly 1/8 of `200[s]`

Then let us try `Pool.map()` on lists of some bigger things, for simplicity, I use a list-of-lists this way :

```
n=10**3
m=10**4
a=np.random.random((n,m)).tolist()

with Pool(8) as p:
    %timeit -r1 -n2  p.map(func,a)
%timeit -r1 -n2  list(map(func,a))
```

which gives :

```
292 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
209 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
```

You see, parallel scaling is gone! 1s ~ 1.76s

We can make it much worse, try to make each sub list to pass even bigger :

```
n=10**3
m=10**5
a=np.random.random((n,m)).tolist()

with Pool(8) as p:
    %timeit -r1 -n2  p.map(func,a)
%timeit -r1 -n2  list(map(func,a))
```

This gives :

```
3.29 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
179 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
```

**Wow, with even larger sub lists, the timing result is totally reversed. We use 8 cores to get a 20 times slower timing!!**

You can also notice the serial `map()`'s timing has nothing to do with a sub list size. So a reasonable explanation would be that `Pool.map()` are really passing the content of those big sub list around processes which cause additional copy?

I am not sure. But if so, why doesn't it passing the address of sub-list? After all, the sub-list is already in the memory, and in practice the `func()` I used is guaranteed not to change/modify the sub-list.

**So, in python, what is the correct way to keep parallel scaling when mapping some operations on a list of large things?**

Comment: What is `%timeit`?

Comment: I'm surprised you see any speedup at all on any of your tests. Multiprocessing comes with lots of overhead (e.g. all parameters and results need to be pickled and unpickled). I don't know what you're measuring with the timeit call either, are you sure you're not measuring the control-thread? As to your question, use standard types, segment the list before spinning up processes, don't measure things from within i/python, and put everything into functions (Python is very slow on global variables).

Comment: @wwii %timeit is ipython magic command, I run these test in jupyter notebook

Comment: @thebjorn Thank you so much for reply. But I am also surpised that you do not believe facts. They are real time elapse, and I can feel it :)

Comment: Are your tests simply measuring the time it takes to serialize and transport the chunks of data to the processes?

Comment: @wwii Hi, thank you for reply. I do not quite understand what you mean. %timeit is just measuring how much time the expression on the same line takes

Comment: @thebjorn I heard multiprocessing has some overhead. But how to solve this problem? Practically, I do have a long list of relatively large dataframe, and I want to do some operations on each of them and each return a small result. and I want to parallel this, because I have 8 cores, I want to use them to get 8 times faster

Comment: Because of the way `p.map`  works: Your first example *sends* a single float to a process 10k times; your second example sends a lists with 10k floats to a process one thousand times; your third example sends  a lists with 10k floats to a process ten thousand times.  I'm not sure it is *fair* to compare the second to the first and comparing the third to the second you an 8x increase in time for sending ten times more data - or said another way you get an 8x increase in time for launching ten times more processes.

Comment: @wwii Hi, thank you so much for comment back. I updated my post with the `func` return just number 1 and add addtional marks. If p.map is really passing large sub list, that will explain the timing. But is there a better parallel approach that can skip passing sub list and directly use data on the main process? I am afraid Thread parallel is not gona work, because python has GIL

Comment: it is strange that the single-threaded version has the same running time for all sizes and it doesn't increases with larger list sizes...

Comment: With Python 3.8, multiprocessing has a Shared Memory class: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html You could try saving your dataframes to shared memory and only pass the memory reference between processes.

Comment: You may like to use a profiler to see where time is being spent.

Comment: It the depends on the problem. If there are only some loops with Numpy functions involved using Numba or with a bit more work Cython (without GIL) would be easier and a lot better in terms of performance (not only because of parallelization).

Answer (score 9):

your work function ends too soon:

```py
In [2]: %timeit func(1)
335 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

so you are basically measuring the overhead of multiprocessing.

change your work function to do more work, like loop `1000 * 1000` times rather than `1000` times, you will see it scales again, `1000000` loops cost roughly `0.4s` on my mac, which high enough compared to the overhead.

below is the test result for different `n` on my mac, I use `Pool(4)` as I have 4 cores, test runs only once rather than multi times like `%timeit`, cause the difference is insignificant:

[image: speedup graph]

you could see the [speedup ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) is increasing proportionally with `n`, the overhead of multiprocessing is shared by each work function call.

the math behind, assume per-call overhead is equal:

[image: ratio = {time_{single} \over time_{mp}} = {cost_{work} * n \over {{cost_{work} * n \over p_{cores}} + cost_{overhead} * n}} = {1 \over {\dfrac{1}{p_{cores}} + {cost_{overhead} \over cost_{work}} }}]

if we want `ratio > 1`:

[image: 1 - {\dfrac{1}{p_{cores}} > {cost_{overhead} \over cost_{work}} }]

approximately equal:

[image]

which means, if work function runs *too fast* compares with per-call overhead, `multiprocessing` does not scale.

Comment: With all due respect, besides the ***per-call**-overheads*, used in your ***Speedup ratio***-formulas, these somehow ignore or omit both the initial add-on costs ( for all processes' instantiations ) and the termination add-on costs ( for releasing the resources ), **which for some scales may dominate the costs-side** of the model **and render any number of free CPU-resources principally un-capable of ever justifying these add-on costs**, that have been paid as expenses, if going parallel, but that will never get rewarded as the **Speedup will become << 1.0 (!)**

Comment: @user3666197 while this answer is for the code in the question, its init cost is relatively small, 0.1s on my mac.

Comment: Well, given own your cited process-instantiation costs on spawn will take **`~ 0.2 [s]`** for all of the 8 sub-processes used by the O/P ( not just those 4 tested ), the ***"relatively small"*** proves itself to be **`200.000 [µs] / 335 [µs] ~ 615 x` bigger** than a posted *cost_overhead*. Last,but not least,O/P has asked "***WHAT*** is the correct way to keep ... scaling ...", which the proposed answer above, promoting a hypothesis (cit.):" *your work function **ends too soon***" simply does neither answer, the less helps to solve or improve to better understand the root cause of the problem

Comment: + the init costs will be always small for "***empty**" python interpreter* (as was a case in the mock-up code above),yet ***in production***,the **real costs will sky-rocket**, as all spawns will copy the fully loaded python interpreter state, i.e. **with all its current data, code imports, everything** because that is how the `multiprocessing` requested process-instantiation ***`spawn`***-method works (full copies enable new sub-processes to escape from the central GIL-lock dance, re-**`[SERIAL]`**-isation of (*just* thread-based) code-execution, which retains all costs, but gets no speedup)

Comment: @user3666197 well, you are correct, then I have no clue why use multiprocessing for such a simple work function.

Comment: **Always welcome,** @georgexsh **glad you've recognised & accepted all facts & arguments.**

Answer (score 9):

<sub>**Before we start** and dive deeper into any hunt for nanoseconds ( and right, it will soon start, as each ns matters as the scaling opens the whole Pandora Box of the problems ), **let's agree on the scales** - most easy and often *"cheap"* premature tricks may and often will derail your dreams once the scales of the problem size have grown into realistic scales - the thousands (seen above in both iterators) behave way different for **in-cache computing** with `< 0.5 [ns]` data-fetches, than once having grown beyond the L1/L2/L3-cache-sizes for scales **above `1E+5, 1E+6, 1E+9,`** above `[GB]`s, **where** each mis-aligned **fetch is WAY more EXPENSIVE, than a few `100 [ns]`**</sub>

> **Q** : *"... because I have 8 cores, **I want to use them to get 8 times faster**"*

*I wish you could, indeed*. Yet, sorry for telling the truth straight, the world does not work this way.

See this **interactive tool**, it will show you both the **speedup limits** and their **principal dependence** on the actual production costs of the real-world scaling of the initial problem, as it grows from trivial sizes and these combined effects **at scale** <sub>*just **click**-it and **play** with the sliders to see it live, in action*</sub> :
 [image: Animated UI-interactive Law of Diminishing Returns, re-formulated so as to also contain processing add-on setup / termination overheads]

> **Q** : *<sub>(is)</sub>`Pool.map()` really passing the content of those big sub list around processes which cause additional copy?*

Yes,
it must do so, by design
plus it does that **by passing all that data *"through"* another *"expensive"* SER/DES processing**,
so as to make it happen delivered *"there"*.
<sub>The very same would apply vice-versa whenever you would have tried to return *"back"* some mastodon-sized result(s), which you did not, here above.</sub>

> **Q** : *But if so, why doesn't it passing the address of sub-list?*

Because the remote ( parameter-receiving ) process is another, fully autonomous process, with its own, separate and *protected*, address-space we cannot just pass an *address-reference* "into", and we wanted that to be a fully independent, autonomously working python process ( due to a will to use this trick so as to escape from [GIL-lock dancing](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/gilvis/fourthread.html) ), didn't we? **Sure we did - this is a central step of our escape from the GIL-Wars** ( for better understanding of the GIL-lock pros and cons, may like [this](https://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) and [this](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf) ( Pg.15+ on CPU-bound processing ).

```
             0.1 ns - NOP
             0.3 ns - XOR, ADD, SUB
             0.5 ns - CPU L1 dCACHE reference           (1st introduced in late 80-ies )
             0.9 ns - JMP SHORT
             1   ns - speed-of-light (a photon) travel a 1 ft (30.5cm) distance -- will stay, throughout any foreseeable future :o)
?~~~~~~~~~~~ 1   ns - MUL ( i**2 = MUL i, i )~~~~~~~~~ doing this 1,000 x is 1 [us]; 1,000,000 x is 1 [ms]; 1,000,000,000 x is 1 [s] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           3~4   ns - CPU L2  CACHE reference           (2020/Q1)
             5   ns - CPU L1 iCACHE Branch mispredict
             7   ns - CPU L2  CACHE reference
            10   ns - DIV
            19   ns - CPU L3  CACHE reference           (2020/Q1 considered slow on 28c Skylake)
            71   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA best  case on XEON E5-46*
           100   ns - MUTEX lock/unlock
           100   ns - own DDR MEMORY reference
           135   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA best  case on XEON E7-*
           202   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA worst case on XEON E7-*
           325   ns - CPU cross-QPI/NUMA worst case on XEON E5-46*
        10,000   ns - Compress 1K bytes with a Zippy PROCESS
        20,000   ns - Send     2K bytes over 1 Gbps  NETWORK
       250,000   ns - Read   1 MB sequentially from  MEMORY
       500,000   ns - Round trip within a same DataCenter
?~~~ 2,500,000   ns - Read  10 MB sequentially from  MEMORY~~(about an empty python process to copy on spawn)~~~~ x ( 1 + nProcesses ) on spawned process instantiation(s), yet an empty python interpreter is indeed not a real-world, production-grade use-case, is it?
    10,000,000   ns - DISK seek
    10,000,000   ns - Read   1 MB sequentially from  NETWORK
?~~ 25,000,000   ns - Read 100 MB sequentially from  MEMORY~~(somewhat light python process to copy on spawn)~~~~ x ( 1 + nProcesses ) on spawned process instantiation(s)
    30,000,000   ns - Read 1 MB sequentially from a  DISK
?~~ 36,000,000   ns - Pickle.dump() SER a 10 MB object for IPC-transfer and remote DES in spawned process~~~~~~~~ x ( 2 ) for a single 10MB parameter-payload SER/DES + add an IPC-transport costs thereof or NETWORK-grade transport costs, if going into [distributed-computing] model Cluster ecosystem
   150,000,000   ns - Send a NETWORK packet CA -> Netherlands
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   | ns|
  |   | us|
  | ms|
```

> **Q** : *" what is **the correct way to keep parallel scaling** when parallel mapping some operations on a list of large things? "*

[image]

**A** )
**UNDERSTAND THE WAYS TO AVOID OR AT LEAST REDUCE EXPENSES** :
 Understand all the types of [the **costs** you have to pay and **will pay**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307727) :

- spend as low [process **instantiation** costs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) as possible *(**rather*** expensive ) best as a one-time cost only

  <sub>On macOS, the *`spawn`* start method is now the default. The *`fork`* start method should be considered unsafe as it can lead to crashes of the subprocess. See [*bpo-33725*](https://bugs.python.org/issue33725).</sub>
- spend as small amount of costs of parameter-passing as you must ( yes, best avoid repetitive passing those "*large things*" as parameters )
- never waste resources on things that do not perform your job - ( never spawn more processes than was reported by **`len( os.sched_getaffinity( 0 ) )`** - any process more than this will but wait for its next CPU-core-slot, and will but evict other, cache-efficient process, thus re-paying all the fetch-costs once already paid to re-fetch again all data so to camp-em back in-cache for a soon to get evicted again in-cache computing, while those processes that worked so far this way were right evicted (for what good?) by a naive use of as many as `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`-reported processes, so expensively spawned in the initial `Pool`-creation )
- better re-use a pre-allocated memory, than keep spending ad-hoc memory allocation costs ALAP
- never share a bit, if The Performance is the goal
- never block, never - be it python **`gc`** which may block if not avoided, or **`Pool.map()`** which blocks either

**B** )
 **UNDERSTAND THE WAYS TO INCREASE THE EFFICIENCY** :
Understand all efficiency increasing tricks, even at a cost of complexity of code ( a few SLOC-s are easy to show in school-books, yet sacrificing both the efficiency and the performance - in spite of these both being **your main enemy** in a fight for a sustainable performance throughout the **scaling** ( of either of problem size or iteration depths, or when growing both of them at the same time ).

Some categories of the real-world costs from **A** ) have [dramatically **changed the limits**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) of the theoretically achievable speedups to be expected from going into some form of `[PARALLEL]` process orchestrations ( here, making some parts of the code-execution got executed in the spawned sub-processes ), the initial view of which was first formulated by Dr. Gene Amdahl as early as 60+ years ago ( for which there were recently added two principal extensions of both the process instantiation(s) related ***setup*** + ***termination** add on costs* ( extremely important in py2 always & py3.5+ for MacOS and Windows ) and an `atomicity-of-work`, which will be discussed below.

### Overhead-strict re-formulation of the Amdahl's Law speedup S:

```
S   = speedup which can be achieved with N processors
s   = a proportion of a calculation, which is [SERIAL]
1-s = a parallelizable portion, that may run  [PAR]
N   = a number of processors ( CPU-cores ) actively participating on [PAR] processing

               1
S =  __________________________; where s, ( 1 - s ), N were defined above
                ( 1 - s )            pSO:= [PAR]-Setup-Overhead     add-on cost/latency
     s  + pSO + _________ + pTO      pTO:= [PAR]-Terminate-Overhead add-on cost/latency
                    N
```

### Overhead-strict and resources-aware re-formulation:

```
                           1                         where s, ( 1 - s ), N
S =  ______________________________________________ ;      pSO, pTO
                   | ( 1 - s )             |               were defined above
     s  + pSO + max|  _________ , atomicP  |  + pTO        atomicP:= a unit of work,
                   |     N                 |                         further indivisible,
                                                                     a duration of an
                                                                     atomic-process-block
```

---

### Prototype on target CPU/RAM device with your python, scaled >>`1E+6`

Any simplified mock-up example will somehow skew your expectations about how the actual workloads will perform in-vivo. Underestimated RAM-allocations, not seen at small-scales may later surprise at scale, sometimes even throwing the operating system into sluggish states, swapping and thrashing. Some smarter tools ( `numba.jit()` ) may even analyze the code and shortcut some passages of code, that will never be visited or that does not produce any result, so be warned that simplified examples may lead to surprising observations.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import os

SCALE = int( 1E9 )
STEP  = int( 1E1 )
aLIST = np.random.random( ( 10**3, 10**4 ) ).tolist()

#######################################################################################
#   func() does some SCALE'd amount of work, yet
#                                                passes almost zero bytes as parameters
#                                                allocates nothing, but iterator
#                                                returns one byte,
#                                                invariant to any expensive inputs
def func( x ):  
    for i in range( SCALE ):
        i**2
    return 1
```

A few hints on making the **strategy of scaling** less overhead-costs expensive :

```
#####################################################################################
#   more_work_en_block() wraps some SCALE'd amount of work, sub-list specified
def more_work_en_block( en_block = [ None, ] ):
    return [ func( nth_item ) for nth_item in en_block ]
```

If indeed must pass a big list, better pass larger block, with remote-iterating its parts ( instead of paying transfer-costs for each and every item passed many many more times, than if using `sub_blocks` ( parameters get SER/DES processed ( ~ the costs of `pickle.dumps()` + `pickle.loads()` ) [per-each-call], again, at an add-on costs, that decrease the resulting efficiency and worsen the overheads part of the extended, overhead-strict Amdahl's Law )

```
#####################################################################################
#   some_work_en_block() wraps some SCALE'd amount of work, tuple-specified
def some_work_en_block( sub_block = ( [ None, ], 0, 1 ) ):
    return more_work_en_block( en_block = sub_block[0][sub_block[1]:sub_block[2]] )
```

---

### Right-sizing the number of process-instances :

```
aMaxNumOfProcessesThatMakesSenseToSPAWN = len( os.sched_getaffinity( 0 ) ) # never more

with Pool( aMaxNumOfProcessesThatMakesSenseToSPAWN ) as p:
     p.imap_unordered( more_work_en_block, [ ( aLIST,
                                               start,
                                               start + STEP
                                               )
                                           for start in range( 0, len( aLIST ), STEP ) ] )
```

Last but not least, expect immense performance boosts from smart use of `numpy` smart vectorised code, best without repetitive passing of static, pre-copied (during the process instantiation(s), thus paid as the reasonably scaled, here un-avoidable, cost of thereof ) BLOBs, used in the code without passing the same data via parameter-passing, in a vectorised ( CPU-very-efficient ) fashion as read-only data. Some examples on how one **can make `~ +500 x` speedup** one may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729273) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068887), about but **`~ +400 x` speedup** or about a case of just about a **`~ +100 x` speedup**, with some examples of some problem-isolation [testing scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594399).

Anyway, the closer will the mock-up code be to your actual workloads, the more sense the benchmarks will get to have ( at scale & in production ).