# Parallel computing: how to share computing resources among users?

Tags: linux, performance, parallel-processing, linux-kernel, parallelism-amdahl

I am running a simulation on a Linux machine with the following specs.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                80
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-79
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    20
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6148 CPU @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               3099.902
CPU max MHz:           3700.0000
CPU min MHz:           1000.0000
BogoMIPS:              4800.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              28160K
```

This is the run command line script for my solver.

```
/path/to/meshfree/installation/folder/meshfree_run.sh    # on 1 (serial) worker
/path/to/meshfree/installation/folder/meshfree_run.sh N  # on N parallel MPI processes
```

I share the system with another colleague of mine. He uses 10 cores for his solution. What would be the fastest option for me in this case? Using 30 MPI processes?

I am a Mechanical Engineer with very little knowledge on parallel computing. So please excuse me if the question is too stupid.

Comment: Is the question - Am I better off running this process one time, or kicking it off 30 times? This is a very application specific question and depends on too many variables to answer conclusively. In summary it's a case of 'try it and find out'

Comment: Its just one job. I need to allocate the right resources to it. So on a 40 core machine, with 10 cores already being used, am i better off running the code on 30 processors? Also considering hyperthreading.

Comment: Whats the alternative option you suggest? Why can't you run it and find out what's best?

Comment: The alternative would be to use 60 processes, but i am not sure how the processes are split between the processors. It takes around 4 days for one whole simulation and I am running short on time. I am already in the middle of a simulation.

Comment: Well you'd think before kicking off a 4 day long simulation you'd know the best way to maximize your compute power - usually via using a cut down version (e.g. 10% sample). Again - not a question any one can answer for you as it's too bespoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"What would be **the fastest option** for me in this case? <sub>...running short on time. I am already in the middle of a simulation.</sub>"*

Salutes to Aachen. If it were not for the ex-post remark, **the fastest option** would be to pre-configure the computing eco-system so that:

- check full details of your NUMA device - using **`lstopo`**, or `lstopo-no-graphics -.ascii` not the `lscpu`
  [image]
- initiate your jobs having as many as possible MPI-worker processes mapped on physical (and best each one exclusively mapped onto its *private*) CPU-core ( as these deserve this as they carry the core FEM / meshing processing workload )
- if your FH policy does not forbid one doing so, you may ask system administrator to introduce CPU-affinity mapping ( that will protect your *in-cache* data from eviction and expensive re-fetches, that would make 10-CPUs mapped exclusively for use by your colleague and the said 30-CPUs mapped exclusively for your application runs and the rest of the listed resources ~ the 40-CPUs ~ being "*shared*"-for-use by both, by your respective CPU-affinity masks.

> **Q** : *"Using 30 MPI processes?"*

No, this is not a reasonable assumption for ASAP processing - use as many CPUs for workers, as possible for an already MPI-parallelised FEM-simulations ( they have high degree of parallelism and most often a by-nature "narrow"-locality ( be it represented as a sparse-matrix / N-band-matrix ) solvers, so the parallel-portion is often very high, compared to other numerical problems ) - the [Amdahl's Law **explains**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) why.[image]

Sure, there might be some academic-objections about some slight difference possible, for cases, where the communication overheads might got slightly reduced on one-less worker(s), yet the need for a brute-force processing rules in FEM/meshed-solvers ( communication costs are typically way less expensive, than the large-scale, FEM-segmented numerical computing part, sending but a small amount of neighbouring blocks' "boundary"-node's state data )

The `htop` will show you the actual state ( may note process:CPU-core wandering around, due to HT / CPU-core Thermal-balancing tricks, that decrease the resulting performance )

[image]

And do consult the **`meshfree`** Support for their Knowledge Base sources on Best Practices.

---

Next time - the best option would be to acquire a less restrictive computing infrastructure for processing critical workloads ( given a business-critical conditions consider this to be the risk of smooth BAU, the more if impacting your business-continuity ).

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.

Comment: **Always welcome,** @vikingd - you may like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427809 for both the **performance** impacting details and **interactive graphical tool** (a simulator) of the Amdahl's Law **net-speedups** on the *real-world* `[SERIAL]`-**`[PARALLEL]` workloads**