# Why does ZeroMQ recommend creating one Context for an application?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-computing, pyzmq, low-latency

I've read the part of the guide that recommends creating one Context. My previous implementation of my application had multiple contexts that I created ad-hoc to get a subscription running. I've since changed it to using a single context for all subscriptions.

What are the drawbacks of creating multiple contexts and what use cases are there for doing so? The guide has this following blurb:

> ***Getting the Context Right***
> *<sub>ZeroMQ applications always start by creating a context, and then using that for creating sockets. In C, it’s the `zmq_ctx_new()` call. You should create and use exactly one context in your process. Technically, the context is the container for all sockets in a single process, and acts as the transport for `inproc` sockets, which are the fastest way to connect threads in one process. If at runtime a process has two contexts, these are like separate ZeroMQ instances. If that’s explicitly what you want, OK, but otherwise remember</sub>*

Does this mean that it's just not as efficient to use multiple contexts, but it would still work?

Comment: It "acts as the transport for inproc sockets", which probably means those won't work between different contexts.

Comment: I can see that but is that much different from consuming from the sockets and combining them afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q** : *"What are the drawbacks of creating multiple contexts ... ?"*

Resources consumed. Nothing else. The more `Context()`-instances one produces, the more memory-allocated & the more overhead-time was spent on doing that.

One-time add-on costs may represent a drawback - some people forget about the [Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178416/negative-speed-up-in-amdahls-law/65224536?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#65224536) (and forget to account for setup & termination add-on costs there) where small amounts of "useful"-work may start to be expensive right due to the *(for some, <sub>... it may surprise how often & how many ...</sub>  hidden)* add-on costs in attempts to distribute/parallelise some part of the application workloads, yet need not bother you, if not entering [low-latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#33065382) or ultra-low latency domains. Run-time add-on overheads ( to maintain each of the `Context()`-instances internal work - yes, it works in the background, so it consumes some CPU-clocks even when doing nothing ) may start doing troubles, when numbers of semi-persistent instances grow higher ( also depends on CPU-microarchitecture & O/S & soft-real-time needs, if present )

> **Q** : *"What ... use cases are there for doing so?"*

When good software architect designs the code for ultimate performance and tries to shave-off the last few nanoseconds, there we go.

Using well thought & smart-crafted specialised-`Context()`-engines, the resulting ZeroMQ performance may grow to almost the CPU/memory-I/O based limits. One may like to read more on relative-prioritisation, CPU-core-mappings and other high-performance tricks on doing this, in my evangelisations of ZeroMQ design-principles.

> **Q** : *"Does this mean that it's just not as efficient to use multiple contexts, but it would still work?"*

The part ***"it would still work"*** is easier - it would, if not violating the O/S maximum number of threads permitted and if there is still RAM available to store the actual flow of the messages intended for out-of-platform delivery, which uses additional, O/S-specific, buffers - yes, additional SpaceDOMAIN and TimeDOMAIN add-on latency & latency jitter costs start to appear in doing that.

The Zero-Copy **`inproc://`** TransportClass is capable of actually doing a pure in-memory flag-signalling of memory-mapped Zero-Copy message-data, that never moves. In specific cases, there can be zero-I/O-threads `Context()`-instances for such **`inproc://`**-only low-latency data-*"flow"* models, as the data is Zero-Copied and never *"flow"* <sub>;o)</sub> ).

> **Q** : *"Why does ZeroMQ recommend..."*

Well, this seems to be a part of the initial Pieter HINTJENS' & Martin SUSRIK's evangelisation of Zero-Sharing, Zero-blocking designs. That was an almost devilish anti-pattern to the Herd of Nerds, who lock/unlock "shared" resources and were suddenly put to a straight opposite ZeroMQ philosophy of designing smart behaviours (without a need to see under the hood).

The art of the Zen-of-Zero - never share, never block, never copy (if not in a need to do so) was astoundingly astonishing to Nerds, who could not initially realise the advantages thereof (as they were for decades typing in code that was hard to read, hard to rewrite, hard to debug, right due to the heaps of sharing-, locking- and blocking-introduced sections and that they/we were "proud-off" to be the Nerds, who "can", where not all our colleagues were able to decode/understand the less improve).

The "central", able to be globally shared `Context()`-instance was a sign of light for those, who started to read, learn and use the new paradigm.

After 12+ years this may seem arcane, yet the art of the Zen-of-Zero started with this pain (and a risk of an industry-wide "cultural", not a technical, rejection).

Until today, this was a brave step from both Pieter HINTJENS & Martin SUSTRIK.

Ultimate ~Respect!~ to the whole work they together undertook... for our learning their insights & chances to re-use them in BAU... without an eye-blink.

Great minds.

Comment: Thank you. what do you mean by Zero-Copied please?

Comment: @Avv: the author of this answer has been invited to take some time off from the site. I don't think they have left any contact details in their profile. Perhaps you could ask a new question, fully describing the problem you are trying to solve?